Слайдер изображений для предпросмотра карточки товара на нативном js
Я в поисках слайдера изображений для предпросмотра карточки товара как это сделано например на Озоне.

По ховеру должен изменяться src изображения. И должны быть доты.
Слайдер должен быть написан на нативном js либо использовать jquery, то есть плагины, написанные для реакта или vue мне не подходят.
Может кто знает подходящий слайдер? Очень бы хотелось избежать самописного кода.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
